# Python3: Download PDF to memory and convert first page to image

Tags: python-3.x, image, pdf, download

i try to do the following:

- Download a PDF file to memory
- Convert the first page to an image
- Use that image with tweepy

I tried the following code, but run into an error.

```
from PIL import Image
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
from urllib.request import urlopen
from io import StringIO, BytesIO

url = 'http://somedomain.com/assets/applets/internet.pdf'
scrape = urlopen(url) # for external files
pdfFile = BytesIO(scrape.read())
pdfFile.seek(0)
pages = convert_from_path(pdfFile,last_page=1, dpi=100)

for page in pages:
    page.save('/home/out.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert '_io.BytesIO' object to str implicitly
```

The generated image should later be used to upload it to twitter by tweepy. I don't need to store it to disk, that's why i try to do all in memory.
Anybody who could help me please?

Comment: You need to use `convert_from_bytes` method instead of `convert_from_path`

Comment: @kip I changed the code to 
pages = convert_from_bytes(pdfFile,last_page=1, dpi=100)

Also imported this function, but still get an error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BytesIO'

Comment: try pass to above method a `bytes` from the `BytesIO` object, maybe with `getvalue()`, something like: `convert_from_bytes(pdfFile.getvalue()`, but I think that `scrape.read()` return a `bytes` object.... `convert_from_bytes(scrape.read()`

Comment: To use scrape.read() directly did the trick. Thank you a lot.